# How to retrieve an ID array and then use that to retrieve documents from Firestore in React Native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am fairly new to both *Firebase* and *React Native*. In the *Firestore*, I have set up a "users" collection where each user document has an array of IDs representing events he has selected.
[image]

These IDs correspond to the name of the event documents in the "events" collection. [image]

In *React Native*, I am trying to retrieve the selectedEvents array from the user before using this IDs array to retrieve the actual events and render them in a FlatList. The FlatList uses a state called "events" as data. Here is my code:

```js
function SelectedScreen(props) {
  // The events array to be displayed in the FlatList
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const userRef = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.id);
  const eventsRef = firebase.firestore().collection("events");

  function onRefresh() {
    // An empty array to push events into
    const newSelected = [];
    userRef
      .get()
      .then((userDoc) => {
        // The retrieved ID array
        const selectedIds = userDoc.data().selectedEvents;
        // For each ID in the array, get the corresponding
        // event document from the "events" collection
        // and push it into the newSelected array
        selectedIds.forEach((eventId) => {
          eventsRef
            .doc(eventId)
            .get()
            .then((eventDoc) => {
              const event = eventDoc.data();
              newSelected.push(event);
            })
            .catch((error) => alert(error));
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error));
    // Set the events to be the newSelected array
    setEvents(newSelected);
  }

  return (
    // A simple button to retrieve the events when pressed
    <Button title="Refresh" onPress={onRefresh} />
    // A button to log the events to the console for testing
    <Button title="Test" onPress={() => console.log(events)} />
    // The FlatList to show the events
    <FlatList
      data={events}
      keyExtractor={(event) => event.id.toString()}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={ListItemSeparator}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        // A custom component to display each event
        <SelectedItem
          title={item.title}
          dateTime={item.dateTime}
          id={item.id}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

When I press the "Refresh" button, nothing shows on the screen (the FlatList displays nothing). However, when I press the "Test" button after that to log "events" to the console, it shows the retrieved events array as intended.

The problem probably lies with the "events" state, but I don't know how to fix it. Any recommendation for change in both the backend and the frontend will be appreciated too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not appropiately rendernig the list, as your are missing the function to render the elements, that would be something like this:

```
const renderItem = ({item}) => {
  return <View><Text>{item.name}</Text></View>
}
```

Have a look at [this article](https://flatlogic.com/blog/how-to-use-react-native-flatlist/) for detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the issue by using **map** instead of **forEach** to match each event ID to that event, as well as making the function **async** and awaiting each command. Here's my new code:

```js
function onRefresh() {
    const newSelected = [];
    userRef
      .get()
      .then(async (userDoc) => {
        const selectedIds = await userDoc.data().selectedEvents;
        if (selectedIds !== []) {
          await Promise.all(
            selectedIds.map(async (eventId) => {
              await eventsRef
                .doc(eventId)
                .get()
                .then(async (eventDoc) => {
                  const event = await eventDoc.data();
                  newSelected.push(event);
                })
                .catch((error) => alert(error));
            })
          );
          setEvents(newSelected);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error));
  }
```

The events are displayed as intended now, and I am left perplexed as to what exactly went wrong before. Oh well, as long as it works I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You can run all the Promises simultaneously using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
function onRefresh() {
    // An empty array to push events into
    const newSelected = [];
    return userRef
        .get()
        .then(async (userDoc) => {
            // The retrieved ID array
            const selectedIds = userDoc.data().selectedEvents;
            // For each ID in the array, get the corresponding
            // event document from the "events" collection
            // and push it into the newSelected array
            const eventsSnapshot = await Promise.all(selectedIds.map((eventId) => eventsRef.doc(eventId).get()))
            const events = eventsSnapshot.map(evt => evt.data())
            newSelected = [...newSelected, ...events];
        }).catch((error) => alert(error));
}
```